# How to get array value in Laravel form helper

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array $subCatArray

```
$subCatArray = [
    'Category1' => [
        1 => 'product 1', 
        2 => 'product 2'
    ], 
    'Category2' => [
        4 => 'product 3', 
        5 => 'product 4'
    ]
]
```

and select is:

```
{!! Form::select('productselect', $subCatArray, null, 
    ['class' => 'form-control 'data-placeholder' => 'Select Product']) !!}
```

I am getting this in my html

```
<option value="1">product 1</option>
```

I want it to be `<option value="product 1">product 1</option>`

The value of the option should be array value not the array key

Comment: why you need this ? `Form::select` is inbuilt function which works as you get here, and you must change the format as in answer if you want

Comment: Or avoid using `form helper` instead create a `<select>` on your own format.

Comment: And also, your `$subCategoryArray` kesy are `['Category1', 'Category2']` not `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you have to update your array so `key` and `value` are equal. Like so:

```
$subCatArray = [
    'Category1' => [
        'product 1' => 'product 1', 
        'product 2' => 'product 2'
    ], 
    'Category2' => [
        'product 3' => 'product 3', 
        'product 4' => 'product 4'
    ]
]
```

The form helper uses the array key as the option value and the array value as the option text.

Comment: but i need to use key number somewhere else as well so i cannot change the array structure

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there's a way with laravelcollective if you want to keep your array structur you will need to make the select with html and inside it loop with foreach and print the value two times on between the option tag and one in the value attribut.

Answer (score 0):

> Retrieve Your array Value using array_get

```
$subCatArray = [
        'Category1' => ['product1' => 'product 1', 'product2' => 'product 2'],
        'Category2' => ['product3' => 'product 3', 'product4' => 'product 4']
    ];


    $value = array_get($subCatArray, 'Category1.product1');

    return $value;
```

Answer (score -1):

> Retrive array to pass to view in dropdown list
>   This is laravel route

```
 Route::get('/calstack', function (){

    $subCatArray = array([
        'Category1' => [
            1 => 'This is oneof product',
            2 => 'this is product2'
        ],
        'Category2' => [
            4 => 'product 3',
            5 => 'product 4'
        ]
    ]);

    foreach($subCatArray as $sub){
      $catefoory =$sub['Category1'];
      $catefoory2 =$sub['Category2'];

    }

    $array_cat_value = array(
        'Categories1'=>$catefoory,
        'Categories2'=>$catefoory2

    );


   return view('welcome', $array_cat_value);



});
```

> This is view file

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <select>
                @foreach($Categories1 as $pro)

                    <option value="{{$pro}}"> {{$pro }} <br></option>

                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```